# 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'categories_'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a python3 project of predicting the outcome of cricket matches using Random Forest Algo for the training of the machine.
I'm currently getting this error 
[image: errorpage-screenshot]

```
**Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/kyvinay/cfd_apriori/4th_umpire/web/fourth_umpire/views.py" in prematch
  107.             probab = pre_match_predict("2016",team1,team2,venue)

File "/Users/kyvinay/cfd_apriori/4th_umpire/web/fourth_umpire/predictions/pred.py" in pre_match_predict
  17.     X_test = enc.transform(X_test).toarray()

File "/Users/kyvinay/cfd_apriori/4th_umpire/web/scikit-learn/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py" in transform
  390.         X_int, X_mask = self._transform(X, handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown)

File "/Users/kyvinay/cfd_apriori/4th_umpire/web/scikit-learn/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py" in _transform
  107.         if n_features != len(self.categories_):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /pre_pred/
Exception Value: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'categories_'**
```

The corresponding code is

```
 import numpy as np
 from scipy import sparse

 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
 from ..utils import check_array
 from ..utils.fixes import _argmax
 from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted

 from ._label import _encode, _encode_check_unknown


    __all__ = [
        'OneHotEncoder',
        'OrdinalEncoder'
    ]


 def _transform(self, X, handle_unknown='error'):
        X_list, n_samples, n_features = self._check_X(X)

        X_int = np.zeros((n_samples, n_features), dtype=np.int)
        X_mask = np.ones((n_samples, n_features), dtype=np.bool)

        if n_features != len(self.categories_):
            #above line is the exception line 107(I'm including this while asking the question).
            raise ValueError(
                "The number of features in X is different to the number of "
                "features of the fitted data. The fitted data had {} features "
                "and the X has {} features."
                .format(len(self.categories_,), n_features)
            )

        for i in range(n_features):
            Xi = X_list[i]
            diff, valid_mask = _encode_check_unknown(Xi, self.categories_[i],
                                                     return_mask=True)

            if not np.all(valid_mask):
                if handle_unknown == 'error':
                    msg = ("Found unknown categories {0} in column {1}"
                           " during transform".format(diff, i))
                    raise ValueError(msg)
                else:
                    # Set the problematic rows to an acceptable value and
                    # continue `The rows are marked `X_mask` and will be
                    # removed later.
                    X_mask[:, i] = valid_mask
                    # cast Xi into the largest string type necessary
                    # to handle different lengths of numpy strings
                    if (self.categories_[i].dtype.kind in ('U', 'S')
                            and self.categories_[i].itemsize > Xi.itemsize):
                        Xi = Xi.astype(self.categories_[i].dtype)
                    else:
                        Xi = Xi.copy()

                    Xi[~valid_mask] = self.categories_[i][0]
            # We use check_unknown=False, since _encode_check_unknown was
            # already called above.
            _, encoded = _encode(Xi, self.categories_[i], encode=True,
                                 check_unknown=False)
            X_int[:, i] = encoded

        return X_int, X_mask
```

This is the original codebase at the Exception Location which seems originally right to me. Any help regarding it would be appreciated.
This is the edited part after attaching the screenshot of the error that I'm getting in bash while running the server locally.
[image: Error Image]
I'm adding the screenshot of the **init** method of OneHotEncoder class here.
[image: __init__ method of OneHotEncode class] 
After changing the **init** method's line

> self.categories=categories

into

> self.categories_=categories

I'm getting the same error. Here is the screenshot for the same.
[image: after slight change in __init__ method of OneHotEncoder]

Comment: You've posted about 20 times too much code here. Please cut it down to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Thanks for the suggestion. I've made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

From part of the code that you deleted:

```py
class OneHotEncoder(_BaseEncoder):
    def __init__(self, categories='auto', drop=None, sparse=True,
                 dtype=np.float64, handle_unknown='error'):
        self.categories = categories
        self.sparse = sparse
        self.dtype = dtype
        self.handle_unknown = handle_unknown
        self.drop = drop
```

This shows you are creating the attribute `categories` but everywhere else in the code you seem to refer to `categories_`.

Comment: I think I may have put the wrong info here as pre_pred is a pickle file and that's where the attribute error is getting. What do you say about that?

Comment: According to your answer, should I change self.categories to self.categories_ or change the right side of this line from categories to categories_ ?  How could that be helpful to me ?

Comment: @vinay, everywhere else in your class you refer to `categories_`, so changing the attribute to `categories_` is probably easiest.  The line would be `self.categories_=categories`

Comment: I've checked it now and it doesn't solve the problem here. The code is I think modular or prepared not to mess with here I think. For your reference I'm attaching another image here that I'm getting in the bash while running the server and checking for the prediction error.

Comment: Please refer to the link  https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXpIk.png for further error screenshot that I've attached in the question.

Comment: This shows the same error as before. Can you post what your init method of the OneHotEncoder class again?

Comment: I've added the same. Please refer here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8iMi.png

Comment: I've changed it back to the original after getting the same error and it's the original code that I've posted in the screenshot I'm referring to.

Comment: I really believe that if you change the line in init to `self.categories_=categories` it will fix the error. Can you post a screenshot with that can in the init and the error still there?

Comment: I've updated the same and still getting the same error. Please refer to link for the screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/85SXM.png

Comment: I've updated the code first then started the local sever and still getting the same error.

Comment: If possible please refer to the original repository on Github to this link https://github.com/aasis21/4th_umpire and try to run it on your machine locally. Maybe then u will understand the problem after installing all the requirements and dependencies or I will be active here if you solve this one without getting into it. If you run this then maybe you will get the idea where I'm dong wrong.

Comment: In case you need, you may provide me some address where I can send you the complete codefile _encoders.py